# How can I make a FloatTensor with requires_grad=True from a numpy array using PyTorch 0.4.0?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Pytorch 0.4.0 introduced the merging on the Tensor and Variable classes.

Before this version, when I wanted to create a `Variable` with autograd from a numpy array I would do the following (where `x` is a numpy array):

```
x = Variable(torch.from_numpy(x).float(), requires_grad=True)
```

With PyTorch version 0.4.0, [the migration guide](http://pytorch.org/2018/04/22/0_4_0-migration-guide.html) shows how we can create Tensors with autograd enabled, examples show you can do things such as

```
x = torch.ones(3, 4, requires_grad=True)
```

and also set `requires_grad` to existing tensors

```
existing_tensor.requires_grad_()
```

I have tried the following three things to try and create a Tensor with `requires_grad=True` which give errors (where `x` is a numpy array):

The first is

```
x = FloatTensor(x, requires_grad=True)
```

which gives the error

```
TypeError: new() received an invalid combination of arguments - got 
(numpy.ndarray, requires_grad=bool), but expected one of:
 * (torch.device device)
 * (tuple of ints size, torch.device device)
      didn't match because some of the keywords were incorrect: 
requires_grad
 * (torch.Storage storage)
 * (Tensor other)
 * (object data, torch.device device)
      didn't match because some of the keywords were incorrect: 
requires_grad
```

The second is to do

```
x = FloatTensor(x)
x.requires_grad()
```

And the third is

```
x = torch.from_numpy(x).single()
x.requires_grad()
```

Which both throw the following error on the second line:

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

These errors give me little hint at what I'm doing wrong, and since the latest version is so new its hard to find content online to help. How can I make a `FloatTensor` with `requires_grad=True` from a numpy array using PyTorch 0.4.0, preferably in a single line?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*How can I make a FloatTensor with requires_grad=True from a numpy array using PyTorch 0.4.0, preferably in a single line?*

If `x` is your numpy array this line should do the trick:

```py
torch.tensor(x, requires_grad=True)
```

Here is a full example tested with PyTorch 0.4.0:

```py
import numpy as np
import torch

x = np.array([1.3, 0.5, 1.9, 2.45])
print('np.array:', x)
t = torch.tensor(x, requires_grad=True)
print('tensor:', t)
print('requires_grad:', t.requires_grad)
```

This gives the following output:

```
np.array: [1.3  0.5  1.9  2.45]
tensor: tensor([ 1.3000,  0.5000,  1.9000,  2.4500], dtype=torch.float64)
requires_grad: True
```

Edit: *`dtype` should be determined by the given `dtype` of your numpy array `x`.*

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this. It seemed I misunderstood what `torch.FloatTensor` does, I thought it was a subtype of `torch.tensor` that enforces a float type. Can you shed some light on what `torch.FloatTensor` is for?

Comment: Please take a look into the migration guide, they have a detailed explanation. They have changed the types. Instead of python data types like torch.FloatTensor all pytorch tensors are now form type 'torch.Tensor'. Instead you should use now dtype, same as it is used in numpy. But take a look at the guide, if you have any questions left just ask :)